# Using Logstash on tarfile to create Elasticsearch pipelines

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, tarfile

I periodically receive gzipped tarfiles containing different types of logs I want to load into Elasticsearch. Is Logstash suitable for this use case? The issue I seem to be running into is that even if I can extract the tarfile contents, Logstash requires me to specify absolute file paths whereas my file paths will differ for each tarfile I want to load.

Answer (score 0):

The file input plugin for Logstash is usually used for "active" log files to read and index data in real time.
If the logfiles that you are going to be processing are complete, you don't need to use the file input plugin at all, it's enough to use the [stdin input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-stdin.html) and pass the contents of the file to the Logstash process.